# Is it possible Connect landphones to mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, phone

I have a land phone that displays the caller ID.
I want to use a some interface or cable to connect the phone to a pc and then connect it to mysql, check if the user is available in the database, and if not, I add him, (name, number, location)

Comment: this question is pretty vague. Any more info ? which phone, which cable, what pbx, etc ?

Comment: @Sirex, I don't know which phone yet, I'll ask the client and tell you, but lets say that you were contacted by a client who want you to create a software for him that displays the numbers of his clients and add clients info, how would you do it? there are phone cables that can be plugged in the pc, the main issue i have is how to connect the phone to mysql or any database whatsoever

Comment: @SomeoneLikeYou As Martin Lee said below, you need a card (probably PCIE) that can handle POTS (Sorry - that should read PSTN). I imagine the manufacturer of the card will have some sort of API which you need to then write an application to sit in between the card API and the DB.

Comment: Most PBX systems let the PBX administrator associate names with numbers and have those displayed on the handset for incoming calls based on incoming caller-ID. The alternative is [CTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_telephony_integration)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick but pbx phone don't tell you the location of the client, he needs the location as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the information from your question, I tend to think that a custom-built system consisting of [Asterisk PBX](http://www.asterisk.org/) and a custom-written software that can query a MySQL database from Asterisk can help you.

The telephone line that you are going to use should probably support the [CallerID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caller_ID) functionality.

Comment: does Switchvox do the job? because it says on the page that Switchvox is easier to use than asterisk

Comment: Could be, but you need a customizable solution therefore open-source Asterisk might be the best choice.